# Twitter style "News ticker" (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, news-ticker

I am looking for a news ticker pretty much identical to the one on twitter (the one the scrolls horizontally)

The main things I am looking for:

Continuous scroll
 - When an element is no longer visible it is removed and put at the very back of the list.
No Pause
 - It should be a smooth scroll, not a scroll, pause, scroll

I attempted to do it by

Setting the ul to `overflow: hidden`
Animating the `li:first` using `margin-left: {current_margin_left}-10`
every second

But it goes way to fast and breaks.

Is there anything that matches this description?

Comment: @jer, this seems a valid enough question. It might be easy to Google an answer, but if it's answered *here* it helps the site to accrue future Google-hits from people that *do* research their questions before asking them.

Comment: @jer I have used google, The issue I find is that all the news tickers seem to be either vertical, or they scroll to the end of the list, and then there is no more content untill the last item is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link consists of a tutorial to create a pure jQuery & CSS twitter ticker which utilizes Twitter’s Search API. It will show your or your friends’ latest tweets, and will not require any server side code  or databases. As a result, the ticker will be easily included into any web page and easily modified to your likings.

Check the below link for detailed info -

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/jquery-twitter-ticker/

Comment: If you could summarize the linked article (just in case that site dies, or re-organizes its material) this would be a *slightly* better answer. =)

Comment: Added a short summary of the link contents. :)

Comment: Grr, I'd like this but it doesn't follow the same horizontal "news ticker" type behaviour..

Answer (score 0):

I think the [jQuery webTicker](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/) would match your description perfectly; the idea was exactly the Twitter one and it took us some time to develop exactly. It also comes with extras like fade-in and fadeout effects; choice of different directions and speeds and also a customisable stylesheet. An additional plus is you can run multiple tickers per page.

I do hope you find this answer useful.